# How to log whole NSException to a text file?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to log a NSException object to a text file and in order to do this I am doing this:

```
///logging modle
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface TextLogModel : JSONModel

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *reason;

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *stack;

    @end


/// logging function

    -(BOOL)log:(NSException*)ex{

        BOOL result = NO;

        TextLogModel* mod = [[TextLogModel alloc] init];
        mod.name = ex.name;
        mod.reason = ex.reason;
        mod.stack = ex.callStackReturnAddresses;

        NSArray* arr = ex.callStackReturnAddresses;

        NSString* json = [[[JsonHelper alloc] init] SerializeObject:mod];

        ......some more code...

        return result;
    }
```

The JSON result I am getting is

> > { "name":"NSRangeException",
>
> "stack":[140735685894180,140735694292846,140735685893869,140735684895768,4295503469,4294976416,4294976329,140735605055272,140735605054845,4295032657,4294975994,140735748324567,140735605907121,140735605995846,140735605995618,140735748324567,140735605995455,140735748324567,140735605988531,140735606350671,140735605982054,140735611658972,140735604907142,140735604892178,140735604013928,140735603475012,4294985938,4294975620],
>
> "reason":"-[__NSCFString
>
> > substringWithRange:]: Range {0, 9223372036854775807} out of bounds;
> >     string length 21"}

**Problem**

The stack is not getting converted to a readable format.

Many thanks for any help that you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by using `callStackSymbols` instead of `callStackReturnAddresses`. But even that is not going to give you all the symbols. That's because the information is just not there (it's not part of the executable because it's not needed during execution).

If you want to generate a full backtrace like the one Xcode or crash reporting tools give you, you're going to need the dSYM file generated alongside your app when you compile.
And you're not going to be able to do this in real time from this app since you're going to need some specific tools that are unavailable from an iOS app.

You should look up crash symbolication if you still want to do that and ask an other specific question about this if there is something you don't understand.